# .NET Workflow Engine Suggestions

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, state-machine, stateless-state-machine

I came across [stateless](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/), a hierarchical state machine framework based on [Simple State Machine](http://codeplex.com/simplestatemachine) for [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/), but configured using C# 3.0

It is easy to configure and use, I will probably use it soon.

But I was just wondering if

- Anyone used [stateless](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/) for real projects (If so what is your opinion?)
- Are there any other good workflow engines for .NET? (other than WF)

Comment: Other workflow engines - you mean, except of Workflow Foundation, right?

Comment: Practical and useful question? Let's close it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been using Stateless and WF for an app that is intended to go into production someday.  :)  I have detailed my experiences so far [on my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258422/comparison-between-stateless-on-google-code-and-windows-workflow).

Overall, I prefer Stateless because it's simpler for more things that WF.  Sure, it's nice to be able to design your workflow graphically, but when you need to implement something more difficult than a sequential workflow (like the state machine workflow), you'll need to work with ExternalDataExchange just to make the right state transitions.  It's probably not hard, but considering that and the fact that you need to implement a persistence service to pause a workflow just seemed unappealing to me.  I don't have a need to persist a workflow to disk for later execution anyway... so I will be using regular events to deal with this in Stateless.  Error handling is easily doable in Stateless (I've been successful with it), but the implementation I've taken is questionable, and is the topic of another discussion (which I'm searching for now on SO!).  I might be posting a question regarding this very soon.

Good luck with Stateless.  I hope to hear how you've been progressing with it.

Comment: There is a project on CodePlex that shows your stateless statemachine graphically. Currently it does not support all the features in the stateless framework. http://statelessdesigner.codeplex.com

Answer (score 5):

For Workflow Foundation, only use it for green project so you can use WF4. Check this out
http://realworldsa.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/goodbyewindowsworkflowfoundationseeyouin2011.htm

WF 1.0 and 1.5 are not compatible with WF4. So it's not a forward solution.

I personally use http://simplestatemachine.codeplex.com as an alternative to WF. I have used it in one full production system (asp.net based) to handle a pretty complex business license issuance system (handling 350+ different government business licenses).

I haven't tried stateless yet but it looks promising.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party.  We've used Stateless in production now for over a year and a half, no issues.  It is a very elegant solution for processing workflows and you quickly integrate the states with your data model.  We represent our states with and int in SQL, so you can run the state machine in ASP.Net in process.  This is true for long running workflows as well.

Comment: Hi David, I would be interested to know whether you still use Stateless for your workflows? Any tips on persisting states in SQL?

Comment: @Mark H - most definitely.  I have found it to be very useful, and I have built several solutions with it.

Answer (score 5):

If your requirements are basic, a very simple StateMachine I wrote may be of interest.

Please be warned that it does not (at the time of writing) support hierarchical states.

You can find it on NuGet:

```
nuget install nstate
```

or check it out on GitHub:

https://github.com/benaston/NState

I hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: I'm reading through your solution on github now.  It's looks interesting.  I've been using stateless for 3 years but I like your approach as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't looked at the [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) it's probably at least worth doing a bit of reading about it.

Comment: I want a more light weight solution

Comment: we all need light weight solutions :)